# Will Juno record its deorbit?

Tags: orbit, nasa, spacecraft, jupiter, juno

I'm really interested about the Juno mission launched in 2011. The spacecraft will reach Jupiter on July 4, 2016, in couple days from when I write this question. It will orbit Jupiter 37 times collecting all different sorts of data, and at the end of the mission, it will deorbit, or just fly into Jupiter's atmosphere and burn up.

There is a visible-light camera/telescope onboard of Juno, so it will be able to take pictures. **Since it is able to take pictures, would it be able to record and send the video of how does travel through Jupiter's atmosphere look like before it burns up?** I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

It would be awesome to have a real footage of flying through Jupiter's clouds, wouldn't it?

Comment: I hope that it will take at least 1 picture right when it enters the clouds so we can see how does it look from inside.

Comment: You might also be interested in this question of mine: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/how-many-extraterrestrial-bodies-have-hosted-a-lander-which-returned-images

Comment: @KKZiomek: I'm afraid by the time it reaches the clouds, it will be a huge ball of fire, and even if it had a camera intact and would be able to take a photo, it would have absolutely no way of transmitting it back to Earth.

Comment: @SF.: And even if it had: While beeing a burning ball of fire, the cameras posibilitys of taking the photo without any noise due to beeing a fireball are.... limited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You won't see Jupiter's atmosphere from the "inside". The entry and destruction of the vehicle is very fast, and occurs relatively high in the atmosphere. Way, way above any clouds. There would not be time to take an image, process it, and get it out the antenna, even if you happened to have Earth in view for the entry. Even if you did have a picture looking up or sideways just before the moment of destruction, it would be like a high-altitude image in Earth's atmosphere, which looks for all purposes like you're in space.

You can of course look down and see the atmosphere, so it would be nice if they did that on the way in and transmitted images for as long as possible. I don't know their intent. In any case, their focus right now is to get into orbit and conduct the science mission.