# Revisiting moon landing sites?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program

Are there any current plans to return to the moon, preferably close to an existing landing site?

After all, it seems like a sound scientific project given that there's talk of human colonization of the moon in the future.

Surely, before any such colonization, we, as humans, would need to ascertain the general condition of craft that have been parked on the surface of the moon and subjected to lunar radiation for 50 years.

Comment: Why land where we already have been when you could land somewhere else for more insight into the surface conditions of another zone? https://www.google.com/search?q=LOPG is the one major thing I know is beginning phases of planning.

Comment: Investigating how materials are affected by lunar conditions would be worthwhile. NASA did with [Apollo 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_12), when the LM landed to close the Surveyor 3 & the astronauts retrieved some parts to return to Earth, after Surveyor 3 had been on the Moon for about two years.

Comment: There are no current, detailed, approved plans to return to the surface of the moon.  At least for the USA. China, maybe.

Comment: After reading both, I think this is a sufficiently different question that it's not a duplicate: [(What happened to the) Plans to visit and/or document sites of previous lunar landings? Are any active now?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27143/12102)

Comment: There is no available rocket for a moon landing. A lot of other important work has to be done besides planing landing sites

Comment: You may be interested in reading about Apollo 12's landing next to a previously landed spacecraft: See [How did Apollo-12 manage to land next to Surveyor-3? First “Space-Tourists”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20353/12102) and also [What was learned from study of Surveyor-3's components, retrieved and returned to Earth by Apollo-12?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20386/12102)